# Getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable with React context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making the website I'm getting issues with the same error in `login.js` and `signup.js`. Here is my `signup.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./Context";
import { initializeApp } from "@firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  RecaptchaVerifier,
  signInWithPhoneNumber,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { signup } from "../../Actions/Auth";
import "./Auth.css";

function SignUpCard({ toggleCardFunc }) {
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*****",
    authDomain: "*****",
    projectId: "*****",
    storageBucket: "******",
    messagingSenderId: "******",
    appId: "********",
    measurementId: "*******",
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = getAuth(app);
 const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useContext(UserContext);  #here get error in this line on isLogin
  const [checked, setchecked] = useState(false);
  const [OTP, setOTP] = useState("");
  const [displayOtp, setDisplayOTP] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleCred = (e) => {
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
  };

  const configureRecaptcha = () => {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      "sign-in-button",
      {
        size: "invisible",
        callback: (response) => {
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
          handleLogin();
          console.log("Captcha Verified ");
        },
        defaultCountry: "IN",
      },
      auth
    );
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    const phoneNumber = "+91" + user?.phoneNo;
    console.log(phoneNumber);
    configureRecaptcha();
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
        // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        console.log("OTP has been sent");
        setDisplayOTP(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  const validateOTP = () => {
    if (OTP.length !== 6) return;
    window.confirmationResult.confirm(OTP).then((result) => {
      // User signed in successfully.
      const userResult = result.user;
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(userResult))
      alert("User is verified");
      dispatch(signup(user));
      setIsLogin(true);
      navigate("/");
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="auth">
      {!displayOtp ? (
        <div className="authWrap">
          <div>
            <p>Display Name</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={handleCred} name="name" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Email</p>
            <input type="email" onChange={handleCred} name="email" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Phone No</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={handleCred} name="phoneNo" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" onChange={handleCred} name="password" />
          </div>
          <div className="tc">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="tc"
              onChange={() => setchecked(!checked)}
              checked={checked}
            />
            <p>
              Opt-in to receive occasional product updates, user research
              invitations, company announcements, and digest.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="sign-in-button"></div>
          <div className="login-button">
            {user.name !== "" &&
            user.email !== "" &&
            user.password !== "" &&
            checked ? (
              <Button
                onClick={handleLogin}
                style={{
                  marginTop: "1.5rem",
                  height: "2.3rem",
                  background: "#0a95ff",
                  boxShadow: "inset 0 1px 0 0 hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 40%)",
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: "0.813rem",
                  textTransform: "capitalize",
                }}
              >
                Sign Up
              </Button>
            ) : (
              <Button
                disabled
                style={{
                  marginTop: "1.5rem",
                  height: "2.3rem",
                  background: "#868686",
                  boxShadow: "inset 0 1px 0 0 hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 40%)",
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: "0.813rem",
                  textTransform: "capitalize",
                }}
              >
                Sign Up
              </Button>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>Enter OTP send to {user?.phoneNo}</p>
          <input
            type="password"
            onChange={(e) => setOTP(e.target.value)}
            name="name"
          />
          <div className="login-button">
            <Button
              onClick={validateOTP}
              style={{
                marginTop: "1.5rem",
                height: "2.3rem",
                background: "#0a95ff",
                boxShadow: "inset 0 1px 0 0 hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 40%)",
                color: "white",
                fontSize: "0.813rem",
                textTransform: "capitalize",
              }}
            >
              Submit OTP
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="login-signup">
        <p>
          Already have an account?{" "}
          <span style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={toggleCardFunc}>
            Log in
          </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          {" "}
          Are you an employer? <span> Sign up on Talent </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SignUpCard;
```

And here is `context.js` which I'm importing for login:

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[isLogin, setIsLogin]}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And here is login.js:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "../../Actions/Auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from "./Context";
import "./Auth.css";

function LoginCard({ toggleCardFunc }) {
 
const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useContext(UserContext);    # here i get error on isLogin
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  const handleCred = (e) => {
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
  };
  const handleLogin = (handleCred) => {
    handleCred.preventDefault();
    if (!user.email && !user.password) {
      alert("Enter email and password");
    }
    {
      dispatch(login(handleCred));
      setIsLogin(true);
      navigate("/");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <img
        src="https://www.vectorlogo.zone/logos/stackoverflow/stackoverflow-ar21.svg"
        alt="logo"
      />
      <div className="authWrap">
        <div>
          <p>Email</p>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleCred}
            value={user.email}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Password</p>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleCred}
            value={user.email}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="login-button">
          {user.email !== "" && user.password !== "" ? (
            <Button
              style={{
                marginTop: "1.5rem",
                height: "2.3rem",
                background: "#0a95ff",
                boxShadow: "inset 0 1px 0 0 hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 40%)",
                color: "white",
                fontSize: "0.813rem",
                textTransform: "capitalize",
              }}
              onClick={handleLogin}
            >
              Login
            </Button>
          ) : (
            <Button
              disabled
              style={{
                marginTop: "1.5rem",
                height: "2.3rem",
                background: "#868686",
                boxShadow: "inset 0 1px 0 0 hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 40%)",
                color: "white",
                fontSize: "0.813rem",
                textTransform: "capitalize",
              }}
            >
              Login
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="login-signup">
        <p>
          Don’t have an account?{" "}
          <span style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={toggleCardFunc}>
            Sign up
          </span>
        </p>
        <p>
          {" "}
          Are you an employer? <span> Sign up on Talent </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginCard;
```

And finally here is my `Auth.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Logincard from "./LoginCard";
import SignUpCard from "./SignUpCard";

function Auth() {
  const [toggleCard, setToggleCard] = useState(true);
  const toggleCardFunc = () => {
    setToggleCard(!toggleCard);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {!toggleCard ? (
        <Logincard toggleCardFunc={toggleCardFunc} />
      ) : (
        <SignUpCard toggleCardFunc={toggleCardFunc} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Auth;
```

I have tried to put what was suggested by VS Code above the line that gives an error:

```
 // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useContext(UserContext);
```

In both `login.js` and `signup.js` but still getting the same error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

Then I tried to comment on the line and got the page but can't able to log in because of the comment. Can please someone help and tell me what the issue is so that my code can work? I'm just getting a blank page right now with the above issue. Please someone suggest something and provide an answer

Here is what exactly the error is from the console.log:

```
SignUpCard.js:31 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at SignUpCard (SignUpCard.js:31:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    SignUpCard @ SignUpCard.js:31
    renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
    mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
    beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
    callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
    invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
    beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
    performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
    workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
    renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
    performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
    flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
    (anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:25651
```

Here is index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {
  legacy_createStore as createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose,
} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import Reducers from "./Reducers";

const store = createStore(Reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: Error is not clear enough. Can you attach screenshot of error from console log ?

Comment: can't able to put images because of the StackOverflow policy of 10 reputations.so now what should i do

Comment: Can you copy paste the error from console log ?

Comment: I have pasted the error above

Comment: Can you show where you are using `UserProvider` ?

Comment: I'm only using UserProvider in context.js that I already provided above

Comment: But I'm using a provider in an index.js that I will provide in the next comment

Comment: Can you show that `index.js`?

Comment: I'M posting it above

Comment: I have posted it in my code index.js

Comment: Thanks @BALBIRSINGH! I pasted an answer, let me know in the comment section there.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you didn't wrap your components inside `UserProvider`. You can do that for example in `index.js` after importing it at the top, like so:

```js
import {UserProvider} from "./path/context"; // ⚠️ use the correct path

...

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
     <UserProvider>
      <App />
     </UserProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: it didn't help still getting the same error